# Android WebView: How to scroll to the end of document?

Tags: android, webview, scroll

I want to stop scrolling when it reaches the document end. I tried the following code:

```
if (_webView.getScrollY() + _webView.getHeight() > _webView.getContentHeight())
    _webView.scrollTo(0, _webView.getContentHeight() - _webView.getHeight());
```

However, based on my observation of different webpages, it mostly stops at about 2/3 of the content, and cannot go to the end of the document.

I'm wondering if those three functions involved are using different units. Based on android document, getScrollY and getHeight are in pixels, but getContentHeight returns "the height of HTML content". So What's the unit of getContentHeight()? Or did I miss something else?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out myself. getContentHeight() must be scaled with getScale(), then it works.

Comment: Thanks, was searching for this for quite some time :). Also useful to measure how far a user scrolled within a page.

Comment: please write the completed code inside of onScroll method that gives you and indication of page end ............